# Power BI DAX: String manipulation--> how to search multiple values and return a mapping value

Tags: string, text, powerbi, dax

For example, I have a column of web site:

```
www.google_b.com
www.amazon_1-3b.com
www.amazon345.com
```

I know that google and amazon are the ones I want to retrieve for another column.

I want to have this column as below

```
www.google-a.com                google
www.google_b.com                google
www.amazon_1-3b.com             amazon
www.amazon345.com               amazon
```

I will have a list of the desired keywords to map with like [google, amazon, facebook, etc]
Does anyone know how to get the dax formula?

It is more like a LIKE "%xyz%" syntax in SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by passing on a SQL like case statement in a `SWITCH`

```
Column = SWITCH(TRUE(), CONTAINSSTRING('fact'[Field],"amazon"),"amazon", CONTAINSSTRING('fact'[Field],"google"),"google")
```

[image: Solution]